Create superuser in ktor
in django, there's manage.py createsuperuser for creating a user with elevated privileges.
For ktor, I have resorted to creating a user programmatically when the app starts, (first checking if the user already exist)
Is there a more elegant or standard way of doing this?
I assume it would be a similar process in other frameworks, express, flask etc since they don't also have that

Ktor doesn't have an admin panel functionality, so the term "super user" isn't applicable.
